# Measure application performance by aggregating SQL audit records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, performance-testing

Suppose there is a simple audit table with two columns (in production there are more columns):

```
ID | Date
```

When the request is processed, we add a record into this table.
Requests are processed in batches, there can be any number of items in a batch. For each item, we will add a record. There will be at least 2 second delay between batches (the number is configurable).

The performance is measured by how fast we can process requests, per unit of time, for example, per second. Consider this sample data (2 clusters, the number of items is equal for demo purposes only):

```
--2016-01-29 10:27:25.603
--2016-01-29 10:27:25.620
--2016-01-29 10:27:25.637
--2016-01-29 10:27:25.653
--2016-01-29 10:27:25.723
--Avg time between requests = 24ms

--2016-01-29 10:27:34.647
--2016-01-29 10:27:34.667
--2016-01-29 10:27:34.680
--2016-01-29 10:27:34.690
--2016-01-29 10:27:34.707
--Avg time = 12ms
```

We can say that at worst, 41.67 requests can be processed per second, and 83.33 at best. Would be nice to know the average batch performance as well.

**Question.** Is it possible to get these metrics using T-SQL alone and how?

*EDIT: To make results statistically significant, it might be useful to discard batches than are less than 10 items in size (configurable).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I've over simplified your request, but consider the following

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Date datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable values
( 1,'2016-01-29 10:27:25.603'),
( 2,'2016-01-29 10:27:25.620'),
( 3,'2016-01-29 10:27:25.637'),
( 4,'2016-01-29 10:27:25.653'),
( 5,'2016-01-29 10:27:25.723'),
( 6,'2016-01-29 10:27:34.647'),
( 7,'2016-01-29 10:27:34.667'),
( 8,'2016-01-29 10:27:34.680'),
( 9,'2016-01-29 10:27:34.690'),
(10,'2016-01-29 10:27:34.707')


Declare @BatchSecondsGap int = 2  -- Seconds Between Batches
Declare @MinObservations int = 5  -- Batch must n or greater

;with cte as (
      Select *,Cnt = sum(1) over (Partition By Batch)
       From  (
              Select *,Batch = sum(Flg) over (Order By Date)
               From (
                     Select ID,Date
                           ,Flg = case when DateDiff(SECOND,Lag(Date,1,null) over (Order By Date),Date)>=@BatchSecondsGap then 1 else 0 end
                           ,MS  = case when DateDiff(SECOND,Lag(Date,1,Date) over (Order By Date),Date)>=@BatchSecondsGap then 0 else DateDiff(MILLISECOND,Lag(Date,1,Date) over (Order By Date),Date) end
                      From  @YourTable
                     ) A
             ) B
 )
Select Title    = 'Total'
      ,DateR1   = min(Date)
      ,DateR2   = max(Date)
      ,BatchCnt = count(Distinct Batch)
      ,TransCnt = count(*)
      ,MS_Ttl   = sum(MS)
      ,MS_Avg   = avg(MS*1.0)
      ,MS_Std   = stdev(MS)
 From  cte
 Where Cnt>=@MinObservations
Union All
Select Title    = concat('Batch ',Batch)
      ,DateR1   = min(Date)
      ,DateR2   = max(Date)
      ,BatchCnt = count(Distinct Batch)
      ,TransCnt = count(*)
      ,MS_Ttl   = sum(MS)
      ,MS_Avg   = avg(MS*1.0)
      ,MS_Std   = stdev(MS)
 From  cte
 Where Cnt>=@MinObservations
 Group By Batch
```

Returns

[image]

---

The image below illustrates that you won't be penalized for the time between batches, so then it becomes a simple aggregation for the final results

[image]

Comment: I think this is perfect to start with, still need to wrap my head around the SQL code. Added `HAVING count(*) > 10` to only include statistically significant data, but my change seems to be statistically insignificant. :) It seems that the system had days of good performance and days of poor performance, with 20x of difference in average processing speed. So calculating a total average makes little sense really. Total AVG=91.21ms, SD=193.52ms. I'm going to add date ranges to try to make more sense of this. Great answer, accepting...

Comment: @Neolisk Happy to help.  Just ping me if you need any assistance

Comment: I see what happened there, even though I added a HAVING clause, it only impacted the number of batches and did not impact the "total" metrics. Can you adjust your SQL, so that "total" skips batches with only a few items in them?

Comment: @Neolisk Updated answer

Comment: Works perfectly. Larger batches perform better, just what I expected. Thank you @John.

Comment: @Neolisk Good to know.  FYI you can use Cnt BETWEEN X and Y as well so if you want to test small batches 0 and 10 or batches between 10 and 25 for example.

Comment: Fortunately, no impact on results, but thanks for the fix.